# PHP/MySQL cell showing info from another recordset

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am creating a PHP/MySQL web site. On one page there is a table which is showing a recordset of users (Recordset1). One of the users field is company (idempresa), where I am storing the id field from the table companies. The table shows the user fields: username, email, company. As you may guess, the cell for the company value shows the company value (idempresa) and not the company name which is part of Recordset2. This the code for the cell:

```
<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idempresa']; ?>
```

How could I update the cell content to show the company name?

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver, how can I do this?

Comment: Thank you @nathanhayfield, could you post your comment as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best place would be in your query as a Left Join. Then you will have both record sets in one. Here is a link to an example: [w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Thanks nathan, I have change the sql part of Recordset1 to this: SELECT *
FROM tbusuarios LEFT JOIN tbempresas ON tbusuarios.idempresa=tbempresas.idEmpresa